# how to go to other Tab by clicking button inside the current Tab in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, web

Hi I want to go to "Menu 3" Tab by clicking the "Next" inside "Menu 2" as shown in below image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUvyi.png)

Here is the code for it:

```
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" disable="disabled">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
         <a href="#">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Please help me with this, also is it possible to make the tab disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this snippet of code to your script.js file i assumed you created it already and then just paste this snippet to it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.next').click(function(){
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#menu3"]').tab('show');
        console.log(1111);
    });
});
```

Here is a snippet i created on bootsnip:
http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/NBK30

Comment: Great job. Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Meily Chhon's code, if you can remove data-toggle="tab" property for 3rd tab, you can prevent showing Menu 3 data when you click on tab 3.

```
<li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
```

Here is the snippest for your response -
https://plnkr.co/edit/WIJHnOr2qVBWUGDjpmHp?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much. I have added it :)